# Tweaking a photoshop smart object JavaScript

Tags: javascript, photoshop, photoshop-script

I found a JavaScript that will make every layer in Photoshop a smart object, which is awesome, but I am wondering if anyone can tweak it for me. I use this injunction with AppleScript. Due to not know much about Javascript I was hoping some kind person can tweak this to select all layers and make one smart object out of all layers in the current file.

The code I am using:

```
// MAIN

var doc = app.activeDocument;
var layers = doc.layers; //array of parent layer/layersets present in active document

for(var i = 0; i < layers.length; i++)
{
   if(!layers[i].isBackgroundLayer) createSmartObject(layers[i]);
}


//FUNCTIONS 

// create smartobject from specified layer (default is active layer)
function createSmartObject(layer)
{
   var doc = app.activeDocument;
   var layer = layer != undefined ? layer : doc.activeLayer;

   if(doc.activeLayer != layer) doc.activeLayer = layer;

   try
   {
      var idnewPlacedLayer = stringIDToTypeID( "newPlacedLayer" );
      executeAction( idnewPlacedLayer, undefined, DialogModes.NO );
      return doc.activeLayer;
   }
   catch(e)
   {
      return undefined;
   }
}// JavaScript Document
```

**Update — Clarification**

The above script takes each layer and one layer a time changes it to a smart object. I want it to select every layer in the document and make it into one smart object without flattening it.

So if I were to do it by hand for an example. I would make a PS doc with as many layers as I want. For argument sake lets say there is 3 layers. I would select the 3 layers(which is all the layer in the doc) and right click and select make smart object. Now I have one smart object with ever layer inside it.

Comment: Not sure what what was changed other then the removal of a thank you in advanced comment. What was the purpose of the edit not made by me? @Mark

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've re-written the code now that I understand that you don't want the layers to be flattened.  This should do the trick!

```
app.preferences.rulerUnits = Units.PIXELS;

getThoseLayers();
createSmartObject();

function getThoseLayers ()
{
  var srcDoc = app.activeDocument;
  var numOfLayers = srcDoc.layers.length;

  // get the top layer
  srcDoc.activeLayer = srcDoc.layers[0];

  for (var i = numOfLayers -1; i >= 0; i--)
  {
    if(!srcDoc.layers[i].isBackgroundLayer)
    {
      addToSelection(srcDoc.layers[i].name)
    }
  }
}

function addToSelection (alayername)
{
  if (alayername == null) return

  try
  {
    var id66 = charIDToTypeID( "slct" );
    var desc14 = new ActionDescriptor();
    var id67 = charIDToTypeID( "null" );
    var ref12 = new ActionReference();
    var id68 = charIDToTypeID( "Lyr " );
    ref12.putName( id68, alayername );
    desc14.putReference( id67, ref12 );
    var id69 = stringIDToTypeID( "selectionModifier" );
    var id70 = stringIDToTypeID( "selectionModifierType" );
    var id71 = stringIDToTypeID( "addToSelection" );
    desc14.putEnumerated( id69, id70, id71 );
    var id72 = charIDToTypeID( "MkVs" );
    desc14.putBoolean( id72, false );
    executeAction( id66, desc14, DialogModes.NO );
  }
  catch(e)
  {
      alert("Whoops! Problem getting layer " + alayername)
  }
}

// create smartobject
function createSmartObject()
{
   try
   {
      var id325 = stringIDToTypeID( "newPlacedLayer" );
      executeAction( id325, undefined, DialogModes.NO );
   }
   catch(e)
   {
      alert("Whoops! Failed to make smart object " + e)
   }
}
```

It works on grabbing all the layers (apart from the background) and selects those layers. I haven't tested it extensively, but it seems to work within groups and even if you have two layers named the same. If it does fail, it will tell you.
Hope you find it useful.

Comment: That is use-full but I am looking to not flatten the file. I want a layered smart object. If you have multiple layers, I want to select them all and then make selected layers into a smart object.

Comment: That not what I interpret "make one smart object out of all layers in the current file." to mean. You need to explain _in detail_ what is wrong with the script you started with and what you want to get out of it.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, I have updated with What I hope is a more detailed idea of what I am trying to do.

Comment: No worries. I've changed the code, so it should work as you want now.

Comment: Works like a charm but I have one question. If I edit the smart object afterwards there is an empty layer with the default "Layer 2" name. Feel bad asking but anyway to not have that blank layer?

Comment: If you have the time great, if not I marked it as a check. Thank you soooo much, I am happy with it.

Comment: I have no idea what is causing that. If you can include an example I can have a look at what's going on.